# This version of µWS is not compatible with your Node.js build: Error: node-loader. while running "truffle console"

Tags: node.js, truffle, nft, ganache

I'm working on a Blockchain project where I use Truffle. when I run the Truffle Console command I face this issue.

Complete Log:

This version of µWS is not compatible with your Node.js build:

Error: node-loader:
Error: The specified module could not be found.
C:\Users\sudda\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\node_modules\ganache\dist\node/3jj9vE3p.node
Falling back to a NodeJS implementation; performance may be degraded.

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "nft-marketplace",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "An NFT Marketplace",
  "author": "clarionnorth@gmail.com",
  "dependencies": {
    "@metamask/detect-provider": "^1.2.0",
    "@openzeppelin/contracts": "^4.3.1",
    "babel-polyfill": "6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-3": "6.24.1",
    "babel-register": "6.26.0",
    "bootstrap": "4.3.1",
    "chai": "4.2.0",
    "chai-as-promised": "7.1.1",
    "chai-bignumber": "3.0.0",
    "mdb-react-ui-kit": "^1.3.0",
    "mdb-ui-kit": "^3.9.0",
    "react": "16.8.4",
    "react-bootstrap": "1.0.0-beta.5",
    "react-dom": "16.8.4",
    "react-scripts": "2.1.3",
    "truffle": "5.0.5",
    "web3": "1.0.0-beta.55"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ]
}
```

My node version is 16.14.0.

How I can remove this error/warning.

Comment: Can you confirm that you are using node version 16? This warning is caused by Ganache but only occurs (as far as I've ever seen) on node 12.

Comment: Yes. I'm sure that the version is 16, further I checked on 14.18.1. It gives me the same error.

Comment: try following this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71810043/how-to-set-up-truffle-and-ganache-with-docker-on-apple-silicon/71810269#71810269 @Frankie

Answer (score 7):

This happened to me with `v19.1.0` while I run

```
truffle deploy --network goerli
```

I switched to

```bash
nvm install --lts  # if version '--lts' is not yet installed.
nvm use --lts

Now using node v18.12.1 (npm v8.19.2)
```

problem is resolved

Comment: This is the correct & the best answer.

Comment: what does it follows to nvm use --lts?

Comment: @IesusDaveSanz Long Term Support. you can read details: https://www.brainspire.com/blog/why-long-term-support-lts-for-your-software-is-a-must

Comment: Best answer, just reinstall using `nvm install --lts` and run `nvm alias default 18`, then everything is working. Switch from node `v20.3.0` to `v18.16.0`. Thanks.