# How to set up Truffle and Ganache with Docker on Apple Silicon

Tags: node.js, docker, truffle, apple-silicon, ganache

error - node-gyp-build: Permission denied while setting up truffle and ganache with docker on Apple Silicon

```
npm ERR! code 127
npm ERR! path /root/.nvm/versions/node/v17.9.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/leveldown
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node-gyp-build
npm ERR! sh: 1: node-gyp-build: Permission denied
```

Comment: Is this a question on an answer?

Comment: my bad, i've re-edited now!

Answer (score 0):

These are some steps i followed to install truffle with docker on my m1 Macbook.
I'll be doing it for ubuntu image container

```
docker run -it ubuntu
```

on your container execute below:

```
apt-get update && apt-get upgrade 
apt-get install sudo build-essential python3 wget curl
```

Then install nvm from https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm#install--update-script

On above link there must be these two commands but with updated versions

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.1/install.sh | bash
wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.1/install.sh | bash
```

then install node and npm with:

```
nvm install node
node install npm
npm install npm
```

after executing

```
nvm install-latest-npm
```

you'll find a statement to update npm to the latest version, execute that command, which should look like, `npm install -g npm@8.6.0`, after that install truffle

```
npm install -g truffle
```

there will be a permission issue in executing above command for which you've to execute

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) <path to node_modules directory>
```

**Note:** the above command has path to `node_modules` you need to find the path to your node_modules from your error. in my case it was `/root/.nvm/versions/node/v17.9.0/lib/node_modules/` so i executed, `sudo chown -R $(whoami) /root/.nvm/versions/node/v17.9.0/lib/node_modules/`

retry `npm install -g truffle`

after this you should be done with installation, but you would face problems where you couldn't execute the truffle file.
for this just allow your truffle file to be executed by running:
`chmod u+x <path to truffle>` you may find the path to truffle with which truffle, execute as below.

`chmod u+x /root/.nvm/versions/node/v17.9.0/bin/truffle`

For Ganache installation:

```
npm install ganache --global
```

To your package.json add,

```
"scripts": {
  "ganache": "ganache --wallet.seed myCustomSeed"
}
```

Then execute,

```
npm run ganache
```

you should be able to see output something like `RPC Listening on 127.0.0.1:8545`

now execute truffle console, make sure you add correct port number like above `8545` in file `truffle-config.js` of your code, when you use it.

now execute `truffle console`